# Error when setting contentscrim color on CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My app recently started to crash on any activity or fragment that has a CollapsingToolbarLayout with the following error log:

`

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radioafrica.music/com.radioafrica.music.activity.PlaylistTracks}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in /data/data/com.radioafrica.music/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0-beta1_f8cf3ba4c70f87f407a745b9fa14a2205d0b587c-classes.dex)
at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
at android.support.design.widget
```

`

When i comment out `collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(color);` , it works fine, but the downside is that i cant set a scrim color and the title doesnt show on the toolbar. Is this a bug with the support library?

Comment: I got the same error when I update my android studio to 2.1.1. No sure if that caused the issue.

Comment: @Shumin Have you tried with a different version of Android Studio?

Comment: I updated to latest one, it's not working. Then I downgraded to 2.1.0, it still not working. My coworker's machine works fine. The only difference is the android studio version so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the error by going through my `build.gradle` file and removing any dependency that might have another version of the `v4 support library`. It seems that the conflicting versions of the libraries were the problem.

Comment: Hi Alex, could you please provide more details? You switched to v4 support library?

Comment: No, i had this library before `com.kogitune:pre-lollipop-activity-transition:1.3.0' which also had its own conflicting v4 support library. When i removed it, everything was fine.

Comment: so how we would know which of libraries have conflict with ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and long time stared on my dependencies versions. 
Then I try remove this line and everything works fine. But I do’t understand the reason, sorry. 
`compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+`

Comment: The conflict appears if you have other dependencies that also have a different version of the support library (either newer or older) from the one your app has by default.