# Error inflating class CollapsingToolbarLayout after adding Settings Activity

Tags: java, android

While developing my working app on Android Studio 2.2, I needed to add a Settings Activity with the dedicated menu New->Activity->Settings Activity.

After adding that, when I try to launch an activity that was previously working based on a Scrolling Activity template, the app crashes and I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.niddu85.fungiatt, PID: 9212
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.niddu85.fungiatt/com.niddu85.fungiatt.ShowMushroomDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ShowMushroomDetails.onCreate(ShowMushroomDetails.java:27)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ShowMushroomDetails.onCreate(ShowMushroomDetails.java:27) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ShowMushroomDetails.onCreate(ShowMushroomDetails.java:27) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in /data/data/com.niddu85.fungiatt/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0_bdc640ee6afefd543417db727c375669ebf3b847-classes.dex)
      at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
      at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:197)
      at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:132)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ShowMushroomDetails.onCreate(ShowMushroomDetails.java:27) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

the build.gradle file is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.niddu85.fungiatt"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

at the end i recreated the whole project using the same source files and it worked.

After some time it happened again!! this thing is getting weird...

Now my project has about 10 WORKING activities and one of them uses a CollapsingToolbarLayout.
After adding a new Google Maps Activity, the CollapsingToolbarLayout it stopped working again.

To understand if was my activity was the problem i created a brand new "Scrolling Activity" from Android Studio, but also this one makes my app crash with the following error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.niddu85.fungiatt, PID: 20858
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.niddu85.fungiatt/com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                         at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity.onCreate(ScrollingActivity.java:15)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity.onCreate(ScrollingActivity.java:15) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity.onCreate(ScrollingActivity.java:15) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in
>   class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its
>   super classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in
>   /data/data/com.niddu85.fungiatt/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0_cf66f3b8dca3dfe86a6c053b41fa65a4ff7d10a6-classes.dex)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrim(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:663)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:197)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:132)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity.onCreate(ScrollingActivity.java:15) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

and my XML layout is the following, the default from Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.niddu85.fungiatt.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `No static method setLayoutDirection`... What sdk version are you using?

Comment: the SDK version is 23

Comment: Alright, then why are you using v24 of the support libraries? Your error says `com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0`

Comment: Don't know, i haven't done that by myself, I just added a new activity and it stopped working. I am new to Android, so i don't know how to fix it, please help!

Comment: Please show the build.gradle file that is in the app directory

Comment: I just edited the question with the build.gradle file content

Answer (score 0):

solved by following the procedure made by ralphspoon adding SDK version 7.0 at this link

[Error inflating class CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423493/error-inflating-class-collapsingtoolbarlayout)