# CollapsingToolbarLayout is not working app crash

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

If i update my dependencies from 23.1.1 to 23.2.0 CollapsingToolbarLayout is not working. App is crashing and throws error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77: Binary XML file line #77: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77: Binary XML file line #77: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V in class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat' appears in /data/app/in.passionconnect.application-1/base.apk)
```

dependencies look like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

and my compileSdkVersion 23  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423493/error-inflating-class-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: use `24.2.0` version

Comment: if i update to latest, it will affect in playstore while updating the apk. because in pervious apk compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"  is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Stable **`24.2.0'`**

**Step 1**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

**Step 2**

```
 targetSdkVersion 24
```

And Then

**Step 3**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Finally **Clean-Rebuild-Gradle** & Run .

Comment: ya i know if i update to latest means sure it will work and already i tried its worked fine. But i need to update complierSDKversion also to latest. In playstore pervious apk, the compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" it will affect if i update means..

Comment: if i update to latest, it will affect in playstore while updating the apk. because in pervious apk compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" is there

Comment: `it will affect in playstore while updating the apk` . No problem . You can use this .Just increase `VersionCode and VersionName`

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the dependencies `com.android.support.***` to the latest version. This may help.

Comment: ya i know if i update to latest means sure it will work. But i need to update complierSDKversion also to latest. In playstore pervious apk, the compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" it will affect if i update means..

Comment: Updating dependencies worked for me. I don't think updating compilarSDKVersion will affect previous play store apk. You should atleast give it a shot.