# Skip multiple activities

Tags: android

Flow of activities

**First Activity->** Activity A-> Activity B->Activity C->Activity D->Activity E

**Second Activity->** Activity A-> Activity B->Activity C->->Activity E
***No need for activity D***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423493/error-inflating-class-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

Comment: show code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For skip you one `Activity` just take a `string` and send that `string` by `intent` to  `NextActivity`.

Try with below code:

**ActivityB :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    //inside click listner
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
                i.putExtra("source", "SKIP");
                startActivity(i);

}
```

**ActivityC:**

```
 String source = "";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

         //if source will skip ActivityD
         if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
         {
           source = getIntent().getExtras().getString("source");
         }

         //inside click listner
         if(source.equals("SKIP"))
         {
           Intent i = new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityE.class); // Here skip ActivityD
           startActivity(i);

         }else{

           Intent i = new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityD.class);
           startActivity(i);
         }

    }
```