# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout in android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I tried to add a parallax view to my android application by using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. But the app is crashing and the log is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gbs.lms/com.gbs.lms.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.gbs.lms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gbs.lms-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.gbs.lms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

**app_bar_home . xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Like LuaPass?\nBuy me a coffee :)"/>
        <android.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried it by using Parallax scroll also then it is working but I cant change it to my required model. I want to set user name in app bar when it is scrolled. For any positive answer thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423493/error-inflating-class-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: The answer of Gabriele Mariotti solves the problem. So, I think isn't a duplicate of that 3 years old question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout"

Since you are using androidx and the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), you have to use [the component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/CollapsingToolbarLayout.md) in the same library. 
Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
 ..>
```

Instead of `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.