# CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't work: The following classes could not be instantiated and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

The CollapsingToolbarLayout crash everytime my application when I try to open it on the device, idk why this problem.
This is the problem:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp/com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.activity.DetailViewerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

And this is the other error which is throw inside android studio (preview of app design)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat.setLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;I)V
```

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.activity.DetailViewerActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarDetailViewer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.android.projectz.sciacallo.thebusapp.com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.activity.DetailViewerActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail_viewer">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_behavior="" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<View
    android:id="@+id/shadowView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_favorit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star_off"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFAB2"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFAB2pressed"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="@string/fab_favorit" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFAB1"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFAB1pressed"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="@string/fab_share" />

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

<!--
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_favorit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_off"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_message"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB1"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
-->
```

The build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.6"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
...

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'

compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.1.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and to finish this is the style.xml file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="InputTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
</style>

<style name="menu_labels_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and this is the jva file:

```
package com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;    
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.R;
import com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.util.ShareUtil;


public class DetailViewerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = DetailViewerActivity.class.getSimpleName();
boolean fabStatus = false;
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
private boolean isFavorit = false;
private String busID;
private ShareUtil share;
private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;
Animation show_fab_1, hide_fab_1;
private com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton fabNormal;
private com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton fabShare;
private com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton fabFavorit;
private View mShadowView;

public Animation fadeIn, fadeOut;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_viewer);

    DetailViewerActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);

    Toolbar toolbarDetail = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarDetailViewer);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarDetail);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);

    share = new ShareUtil();

    //fabNormal = (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_normal);
    fabShare = (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_share);
    fabFavorit = (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_favorit);



    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_backward);

    mShadowView = findViewById(R.id.shadowView);
    //fabNormal.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabShare.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabFavorit.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (isFavorit) {
        fabFavorit.setSize(com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        fabFavorit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star_on);
        fabFavorit.setStrokeVisible(false);
        fabFavorit.refreshDrawableState();
    } else {
        fabFavorit.setSize(com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        fabFavorit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star_off);
        fabFavorit.setStrokeVisible(false);
        fabFavorit.refreshDrawableState();
    }


    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // write your code here
        this.finish();
        DetailViewerActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.fab_share: // fab per lo sharing della tratta:
            /**
             * testo:
             * Stò guardando questa tratta: <nome-tratta>
             * anche te puoi farlo, scarica gratuitamente l'app...
             */
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TAG + ": test_share_fab_share_button_tragitto");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_title)));
            break;
        case R.id.fab_favorit: // fab per il set favorit della tratta
            /**
             * qui bisogna fare i controlli con il database interno per verificare la
             * veridicità dei dati: se la tratta è tra i favorit dell'utente
             */
            if (isFavorit == true) {
                isFavorit = false;
                fabFavorit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star_on);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(v, "Percorso salvato nei preferiti", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("INDIETRO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(view, "Percorso eliminato", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar1.show();
                                fabStatus = false;
                                fabFavorit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_off);
                                fabFavorit.refreshDrawableState();
                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
                //Toast.makeText(DetailViewerActivity.this, String.valueOf(isFavorit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                isFavorit = true;
                fabFavorit.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star_off);
                //Toast.makeText(DetailViewerActivity.this, String.valueOf(isFavorit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            fabFavorit.refreshDrawableState();
            break;
    }
}



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            DetailViewerActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        View view = null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1: /* visualizzazione dei dettaglio del viaggio */
                view = getTravelView(inflater);
                break;
            case 2: /* visualizzazione dei servizi disponibili (città) */
                view = getServiceView(inflater);
                break;
            case 3: /* visualizzazione delle pubblicità dei qualiasi cosa (supermercati, scarpe, viagra ...) */
                view = getAdvertisingView(inflater);
                break;
        }
        return view; //ritornare un layout
    }

    public View getTravelView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_layout, null);
    }

    public View getServiceView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_layout, null);
    }

    public View getAdvertisingView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.advertising_layout, null);
    }
}

public boolean isBusFavorit() {
    return isFavorit;
}

public void setFavorit(boolean fav) {
    isFavorit = fav;
}
}
```

Comment: the error is coming from your java file, please add that too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39118939/5996106

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal the SDK is installed

Comment: @W4R10CK ok I edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem by changing the version of SDK, I change sdk library version from 23.4.0 to 24.0.0, and it works.
I follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/39119028/5996106 @KarandeepAtwal

Comment: Great , Perfect solution !!

Answer (score 1):

Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency. So you should Use only same versions.Its problem of conflicting -

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' //23.4.0


//try to delete these below libraries and see if it works
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' //23.4.0
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0' //23.4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, the build.grandle problem is solved but the application still crash by the CollapsingToolbarLayout
`crash log ->`                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp/com.android.projectz.teamrocket.thebusapp.activity.DetailViewerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;
}
```

Use this in your gradle file.

Comment: I try it but it didn't work, also I try to clean, rebuild and sync the grandle but nothing work

Answer (score 0):

Update manifest like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    {
        force = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is the error:



Error:Could not find method com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0() for arguments [build_bi1o4sgtobev1g9gm56uw9a04$_run_closure2$_closure6@5234b733] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>