# Google play services raising the version of support-v4 (to 24.0.0)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

In my project I'm compiling against `sdk-version 23` and using the compat/support libraries version `23.2.0`.

Now I'm trying to update the `play-services-version` from `9.2.1` to `10.2.0`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
```

But making this change ads the `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0` library to my project making my project to crash due with strange not found errors in the compat libraries like explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386448/error-inflating-collapsingtoolbarlayout).

How can I avoid that? should I skip the play-services update? can I avoid them to raise the version of the support-v4 lib?

Comment: why not just up your project to 24? You should always be compiling aginst the latest sdk

Comment: Can't update my project due to a bad behaviour of another library when targeting version 24+

Comment: you could add an exclude below compile play services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it could work with something like this:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

or if this does not work then maybe:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0') {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support',  module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Or maybe you don't need the whole base play services and only specific packages as defined [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)